# Use hard disk image like a regular hard disk on Linux

Tags: linux, mount, disk-image

If you have a hard disk image (including partition table, multiple partitions,...), is it possible to let Linux treat it as a regular hard disk?

By "regular hard disk" I mean I would like to have the image show up as, for instance, /dev/hdx and its partitions as /dev/hdx1,...

(I know I can mount one of the partitions in the image using "mount -o loop,offset=x ..." but I don't really like this option.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`kpartx`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/kpartx) will generate multiple device files from the partitions within the file which you can then loopmount to get at the contents.

Comment: Yes that does what I want! Just one thing: only the partitions show up as dev-nodes, is it also possible to create a node for the entire device?

Comment: I'm not certain why you'd need to. With the exception of ioctls, a normal file works just like a block device.

Comment: I need it to access the MBR, but you're right: I can do that via the image file as well. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

+1 for kpartx.

For command line fans, partx does the same job.

Comment: Except that kpartx isn't a GUI app.

Comment: Fair enough!  I guessed it might be a kde gui thing...

Comment: Ignore my answer.  Partx appears to be a subtly different tool.