# How to create virtual block devices from file?

Tags: linux, mount, hard-drive-image

- Let's have unknown disk drive uncompressed raw image (created for example by `dd if=/dev/sda of=image`) in single file.
- If we knew the disk layout, we could mount particular partitions from the file as the loop devices via skipping some offsets.
- Let's suppose we don't know the layout. Can we somehow "mount" the whole disk drive `image`, which process would create virtual block devices according to the disk layout? For example having 2 partitions in the `image` would result in creating 3 devices (`/dev/sdx`, `/dev/sdx1`, `/dev/sdx2`). We could then mount such devices as usual.

Comment: What you are looking for is the loop device. You can attach anything on one loop device, then run kpartx against it to discover partitions which can then be mounted.

Comment: @Deltik: Thanks, I have already found similar posts and formulated an answer.

Comment: if it is an image of a single partition you cant just `mount` it directly. Only if the image contains more than a single partition or filesystem do you need a program to parse input and emulate several volumes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more research I have found, there are at least two methods to test:

1. According to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/127926/use-hard-disk-image-like-a-regular-hard-disk-on-linux) post, **`kpartx`** is applicable tool.

   - Unfortunately it didn't work on Arch Linux for me
   - It's from AUR: `yaourt multipath-tools-git`, seems to be not well supported/finished and ended up with errors like:

     > device-mapper: reload ioctl on loop0p1 failed: No such device
   - Can be at least used to list the embedded partitions: `kpartx -l image`
   - **EDIT:** According to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/117136/how-can-i-mount-a-partition-from-dd-created-image-of-a-block-device-e-g-hdd-u) post, it seems to be obsolete and the preferred method is the following one.
2. According to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/344899/how-can-i-mount-a-disk-image) post, **`losetup`** can be used.

   - Firstly it didn't work: `losetup /dev/loop0 image` (missing the devices for particular partitions).
   - Trying again using additional `-P` option did the work: `losetup -d /dev/loop0`, `losetup -P /dev/loop0 image` and `/dev/loop0pX` devices were created.
   - These devices are then mountable as expected, like `mount /dev/loop0p3 /mnt/x -t ntfs`

Comment: I wonder if would work without the MBR/GPT information. What if you cropped the first couple of sectors, so the image starts at the first partition? And are those `/dev/loop0px` volumes writable, as in changes are saved to the original image file?